# Value of n summations of 1 $\sum_{0 \le a_1\lt a_2 \lt a_3 ...\lt a_k \le n}1$

Tags: summation, combinations

I need to find $$\sum_{0 \le a_1\lt a_2 \lt a_3 ...\lt a_k \le n}1$$
My attempt:

I think it is equal to $ ^nC_k $ as
$$\sum_1^n{1} = n = ^nC_1$$
$${\sum \sum }_{0\le i \lt j \le n} 1 = \frac {n(n-1)}{2} = ^nC_2$$
similar pattern should follow. Thus
$$\sum_{0 \le a_1\lt a_2 \lt a_3 ...\lt a_k \le n}1 = ^nC_k$$
I am not sure if this is correct.
Can you prove find the value of the summation. Is there a way to visualize this problem?

Comment: That's simply the number of ways you can choose $k$ different objects among $n+1$ objects ($a_i \in \{ 0, \dots , n\}$). It turns out that the answer is $\binom{n+1}{k}$.

Answer (score 2):

All that summation does is count the combinations of $k$ integers smaller or equal to $n$, since you're literally adding 1 to the sum for each such combination.

Can you figure out the complete solution from this hint?

(Note that since you allow both 0 and $n$, there are $n+1$ integers to pick from)

Comment: I don't understand, how is it calculating the combinations?

Answer (score 2):

For instance,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{0\le k\lt j< i\le n}1
&=\sum_{i=2}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} \binom k0\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\binom {j}1\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}2\\
&=\binom{n+1}3
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$\sum_{0\le a_1\lt a_2\lt a_3\lt\cdots\lt a_k\le n}1=\binom{n+1}k\qquad\blacksquare$$

Comment: The inequalities between $a_i$ are strict.

Comment: @Wojowu - Thanks! Edited accordingly.